# DB2 Linux to Windows Migration

Tags: sql, db2, database-migration, ibm-data-studio

We have a RHEL server running DB2 with one failing hard drive that is several years out of support. I've been tasked with migrating DB2 to a newer Windows server.

What is the easiest way to do this? Is it possible to take a backup of the entire database and restore it on Windows? In the past, the way I've duplicated databases from one DB2 server to another was to export each table from the schema one by one, create the new schema in the new database, then import each table one by one. We have several schemas that require migration, and it would be very time consuming to do it table by table. There must be a better and faster way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restore on Windows a backup taken on a Linux server. Use  `db2look` to extract the DDL statements, then `db2move` to export and load tables *en masse* (you can specify schemas or table name patterns).

More info [in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0005960.html).

Comment: I exported all of the tables then imported. However, when creating the schema, I had to remove all of the constraints and generated always as identity otherwise the import would fail. After the import, I had to get the max value for each identity column, add the constraints, and add the generated always identity starting with a value one greater than the max and incrementing by one. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Not sure about constraints, but here's one [attempt to deal with identities](https://gist.github.com/nickivanov/62c6914e3604f1c79238242083dd667d).